# What version of Silverlight am I using?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, silverlight

I have a Silverlight application that I am maintaining.  I am currently using Visual Studio 2008.  I have the Microsoft Silverlight 3 SDK installed.  I have Microsoft Silverlight 4 installed.  When I run the application and right click on the window to pull up the about Silveright message box it tells my that I'm using 4 which is what I expect.  When I open up the project file in notepad it tells me that I'm importing project $(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\Silverlight\v3.0\Microsoft.Silverlight.CSharp.targets

So I'm fairly certain that I am using Silverlight 3 when I build.  Is there nothing in Visual Studio that will tell me that?  I've been digging around for the big bold "You are using Silverlight Version X" property somewhere, but have been unable to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only build Silverlight 3 apps with VS 2008, so if you are in Visual Studio 2008 it will be Silverlight 3.

You only get a choice of Silverlight targets in Visual Studio 2010.

The runtime is of course whatever your browser is using, but the Silverlight runtime 4 is backward compatible to runs SL 3 apps.

Hope this helps.